# GROUP BY and sum() performance issue

Tags: mysql

I'm performing this query

```
SELECT sum(c.cantitate) AS num, 
produse.*,
cc.seo
FROM produse
LEFT JOIN comenzi c ON produse.id = c.produs
LEFT JOIN cosuri cs ON c.cos = cs.id
LEFT JOIN categorii cc ON produse.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND produse.vizibil ='1'
GROUP BY produse.id
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 14
```

Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 14  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 11.734 sec.
Without the GROUP BY and sum it takes 16ms.
This query is used for a list of top sale 14 products based on quantity sale.
How can i rewrite the query for better performance ?

Comment: do you have indexes on the `SUM` and `GROUP  BY` columns?

Comment: the engine is having to randomly select a value for each column in the select that isn't an aggregate and not in the group by.  Try adding each column in the select to the group by.  Or do you really not care what values are selected from produse.* and cc.seo?

Comment: i need all of them from produse ( products )

Comment: What @xqbert said. When you GROUP BY, you absolutely must add every column into your GROUP BY that isn't being aggregated in your SELECT. Don't let your RDBMS make random decisions about what data it returns on your behalf. MySQL is the only RDBMS that actually allows you to do this. Any other RDBMS would just throw an error until you added your non-aggregated columns into your GROUP BY. MySQL is silly like that.

Comment: i have indexes on both SUM and GROUP BY columns

Comment: @JNevill i'll give it a try

Comment: Also... do you wan the sum of comenzi before the joins to cosuri and categorii which may have multiple records causing an inflated sum or after the join with perhaps an inflated sum?

Comment: here is a clue to save us all of misery. Publish `show create table xxx` for all the tables in question. Publish the results

Comment: @xQbert and JNevill - although I agree that all required fields should be listed in the group by clause, however, mysql does not randomly choose the data that appears in the fields, that are neither in the group by clause, nor are aggregated.

Comment: @Drew and publish the results of the explain as well

Comment: @Shadow yes it does [Link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html) "MySQL extends the use of GROUP BY so that the select list can refer to nonaggregated columns not named in the GROUP BY clause....The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. " and by default too!  One of the less endearing qualities of mySQL IMO.

Comment: @xQbert The fact that the server is free to choose does not mean that it chooses randomly. The values picked are determined by the position of the affected records within the file and ordering of the resultset. In plain English: mysql will pick the 1st value it encounters while processing the data. This means that in most cases inadvertently this approach produces the right results.

Comment: ok poor chose of words.  I would say Random vs indeterminate are synonyms in this case; but perhaps not.  Regardless. there's an opportunity where the system may not return desired results; thus I would say not listing the non-aggregated columns in the group by is taking a risk on the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to generate the sum's before the joins...

**Per Comment to note against original Question:**

Do you want the sum of comenzi before the joins to cosuri and categorii which may have multiple records causing a potentially inflated sum or after the join with perhaps an inflated sum?

```
SELECT c.cantitate AS num, 
produse.*,
cc.seo
FROM produse
LEFT JOIN (Select produs, cos, sum(cantitate) as cantitate 
           FROM comenzi 
           GROUP BY produs, cos) c ON produse.id = c.produs
LEFT JOIN cosuri cs ON c.cos = cs.id
LEFT JOIN categorii cc ON produse.categorie = cc.id
WHERE cs.status = 'closed' AND produse.vizibil ='1'
ORDER BY num DESC
LIMIT 14
```

Example:
If comenzi has a record with ID 1 and a cos of 'A' and a cantitate of 3
and joins to cosuri based on CS.ID which has ID 'A' listed 3 times then the sum for cantitate will be calculated 3+3+3 (9)  instead of Just 3... which could be the problem.  If we calculate the sum in advance, we avoid the problem (if it is  one) and the overhead of summing that values perhaps thousands of times depending on the cardinality between cosuri and categorii to comenzi.  Which... could improve performance.

*To know for certain if this would improve performance we would actually need to*

1. Understand requirements of the results (Sum before join or after?)
2. See some sample data along with statistics of each table to know the record counts
3. Knowledge of indexes between table joins and any where clause
   criteria
4. A view of the explain plan on the database.

Without these details we can't know for certain what would truly help.  Everything is a guess without the facts; which there are few of here)

Comment: I did delete the comment, it seemed petty.  I have tried to improve the answer to address the cardinality issue.  However to say the question wasn't asked... it was.  This "Answer" was to address the summation problem if it exists (which based on past experience likely does)  @Drew: thank's for putting me in the right frame of mind again.

Comment: honestly I didn't even read any of it before I posted that. So I may have been rude. Sorry. Edit: I read some but was in a quandary